# DispatchGroup not working with URLSession.shared.dataTask

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to implement many concurrent api calls through URLSession.shared singleton. What I want is that they are made concurrently so when I had all the responses, then execute the completion handler (I took this as example: https://medium.com/@oleary.audio/simultaneous-asynchronous-calls-in-swift-9c1f5fd3ea32):

```
init(completion: (()->Void)? = nil) throws {
    self.myToken = myToken

    let group = DispatchGroup()

    group.enter()
    print("Downloading User")

    self.downloadUser(completion: { userObject in
        self.userObject = userObject
        group.leave()
    })

    group.enter()
    print("Downloading Tickets")

    self.downloadTickets(completion: { ticketsObject in
        if let ticketsObject   = ticketsObject {
            self.ticketsObject = ticketsObject
        }
        group.leave()
    })

    group.wait()

    completion?()
}
```

Then the functions the implement the api calls are something like:

```
private func downloadUser( completion: @escaping ((myUsuario)->Void )) {
    let url = URL(string: "\(Globals.laravelAPI)me")
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
        (data:Data?, response:URLResponse?, error:Error?) in

        if let error = error {
            ...
        }
        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,(200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else { ... }
        if let data = data {
            do {
                let user = try JSONDecoder().decode(myUsuario.self, from: data)
                completion(user)
            } catch {
                print("USER PARSING ERROR: \(error)")
                fatalError()
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

When I run the program, it make the calls but never get the responses so the `group.wait()` is never executed.

Comment: 1. Your `downloadUser` function must call the `completion` handler no matter what happens. 2. Don't use `group.wait()`. Use `group.notify` and call the completion block inside the `notify` block.

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks a lot!